# Looking for average temperature data for Afghanistan

Tags: data, climate, afghanistan

Hey all I am looking for a average temperature data for Afghanistan monthly over a year, precipitation would work too. In a shapefile, if anyone has any or knows anywhere that I could access one please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

[WorldClim](http://www.worldclim.org/) makes this type of information available - not specific to any country, but you can grab a grid of the applicable area. Note that there is a "not for commercial use" restriction, however you may be able to get permission - I have not tried.

Answer (score 2):

**Climate Services - 14th Weather Squadron**

https://notus2.afccc.af.mil/SCISPublic/services/databases.asp

They use the code `AGRI` for Weather Stations in Afghanistan

```
"The Afghanistan sites can be identified with a networktype of ‘AGRI’. Periods of records vary form station to station.
Purpose: Support DoD projects.
Time_Period_of_Content:
Time_Period_Information:
Range_of_Dates/Times:
Beginning_Date: 19280101/0000Z
Ending_Date: Present
Currentness_Reference: Data are available upon receipt
Status:
Progress: In work
Maintenance_and_Update_Frequency: Monthly"
```